# Why is the size of a character literal in C different than in C++

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

I know that every literal in C and C++ get a specific type information.
I have written this little program in C and compiled this in Visual Studio 2012.
The source file is called 'main.c'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("sizeof(char) = %d\n",sizeof(char));
    printf("sizeof('i') = %d",sizeof('i'));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof(char) = 1
sizeof('i') = 4
```

I wondered that the size of a character wasn't 1 Byte. I renamed the source file to 'main.cpp' and now sizeof('a') returned 1 as previously expected. So there must be a language specific difference. Why is the size of a char in C 4 Byte and not 1 ?

Comment: *Q: Why is the size of a char in C different than in C++?* A: It isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, `'i'` has type `int` for backwards-compatibility reasons. Thus `sizeof('i')` shows the size of an `int` on the chosen compilation platform.

In C++, because overloading made it more urgent to avoid giving surprising types to expression, it was decided to break backwards compatibility and to give `'i'` the type `char`.

Answer (score 10):

Because in C++ the type of character literals is `char`, while in C it is `int`. Of course `sizeof(char)` itself is 1 in both languages by definition.

Comment: *Why is the size of a character literal in C different than in C++?* Your answer is *in C++ the type of character literals is char, while in C it is int*. I guess the underlying OP question is: why is a character literal `int` in C and not `char` as in C++.

Comment: @ouah: I can't agree with that. The question says "why is the size of a char....", which clearly highlights a misconception: that a character literal is of type `char`. One would need to clear that up before being in the position to ask why it happens.